# Angular ng-grid - opening a datepicker on editable cell column on button click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid (v2.0.13) and i want open a datepicker on editable cell  column when a user hit "EDIT" button.

So far, i am just able to make a single cell column editable. Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/q2kyroys/10/)

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngGrid"]);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

$scope.edit = function (row) {
    row.edit = !row.edit;
};
$scope.myData = [{
    name: "Moroni",
    date: new Date()
}, {
    name: "Tiancum",
    date: new Date()
}, {
    name: "Jacob",
    date: new Date()
}, {
    name: "Nephi",
    date: new Date()
}];


$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enableRowSelection: false,
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'name',
        displayName: 'Name'
    }, {
        field: 'date',
        displayName: 'Date',
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.edit">{{row.getProperty(col.field) | date:"MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a"}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-show="row.edit"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.date"/></div></div>',
        cellFilter: 'date:"dd.MM.yyyy"'
    }, {
        displayName: 'Edit',
        cellTemplate: '<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(row)" >Edit</button> '
    }]
};
```

});

Its working as expected. Now i want to open a date-picker (ui-bootstrap) for selecting a new date.

I tried and googled and found one solution, [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kJYDYx?p=preview), but i am unable to integrate it with my code.

Is there a way to accomplish the desired functionality using the above link or any other way to fix the issue.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve? Editing a single row or opening a date picker?  Your question isn't very clear, and "unable to integrate with my code" doesn't explain what happens when you try.

Comment: just as an aside, I wouldn't trust any angular code that uses `!scope.$$phase`.

Comment: Sorry for wrong title. I want to add a datepicker. Updated the title as well :)